# Ubuntu installer doesn't start

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu in my Windows 10 machine but I can't. I want to create a partition with windows and Ubuntu but the install doesn't work.

When I try to load up Ubuntu from my USB drive, it let me select the install Ubuntu and then the pc stops doing anything.
What I did:

- Created some space for Ubuntu
- Safe and fast boot deactivated
- Created an image of Ubuntu in my USB
- select the USB as the first boot device

As soon as I select "install ubuntu" the pc stops working and nothing happens (the pc is still on but it doesn't go anything)

Comment: Will USB boot in try mode? If not then check for corrupt ISO using MD5SUM.

Comment: Probably a corrupted ISO image. That happens fairly often. Try another way of moving the ISO image to the USB stick and/or use a different USB stick.

Comment: What tool did you use in order to create your USB stick? You can follow [this tutorial ](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1) when you want to try it again with Rufus.